# Escape @Model to parse to string

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a string like so:`I don't like fish`. It is in my model, and I am trying to read it to an element in my form, like this:

```
if ("@Model.Text" != "") {
    $('#inputMethod').val(@Model.Text);
}
```

The problem is that the browser throws an error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`
If I change the code to this:

```
if ("@Model.Text" != "") {
    $('#inputMethod').val(String("@Model.Text"));
}
```

It renders the text, but it is like this: `I don&#39;t like fish`. I want the text to format normally, with the apostrophe. How can I get the javascript to recognize the last `)`?

Comment: Have you tried `.val((@Model.Text))` ?

Comment: Change it to `.val("@Model.Text");`

Comment: Yeah, tried both of those. `((@Model.Text))` gave me the same error, `("@Model.Text")` kept the escape sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Model.Text` is `"apple"`, then you have this:

```
$('#inputMethod').val(@Model.Text);
```

Rendering as this:

```
$('#inputMethod').val(apple);
```

Without the quotes. You can write this instead:

```
$('#inputMethod').val(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Text)));
```

To render this:

```
$('#inputMethod').val("apple");
```

This method will work even when your text contains strange symbols, quotes, etc.

Comment: @WookieCoder Rob's comment was on my answer before I edited it. His comment was correct then but no longer applies.

Comment: @Rob You might want to remove your comment now, because it no longer applies after my edit.

Comment: @WookieCoder Prefer the Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...)) version. It will work for any string.